# AppBar changes background color when a TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

The AppBar is initially set to 1% opacity black color, but when a texfield is focused, the app bar changes to black.

```dart
class _MyLoginPageState extends State<MyLoginPage> {
  AppAssets appAssets = AppAssets();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: appbarColor,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Login',
          style: AppTextStyles.heading(),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
            decelerationRate: ScrollDecelerationRate.fast),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            const BgCirlces(position: "topLeft", shadowColor: accentBlue),
            const BgCirlces(position: "bottomLeft", shadowColor: accentYellow),
            const BgCirlces(position: "topRight", shadowColor: accentPink),
            const BgCirlces(position: "bottomRight", shadowColor: accentGreen),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 36),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints:
                          const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 300, minHeight: 280),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          const MyInput(
                            placeholder: 'Username',
                          ),
                          const MyInput(
                            placeholder: 'Password',
                          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`myInput` is the one causing change in app bar color.

code for `myInput()`

```dart
class MyInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final String placeholder;
  const MyInput({super.key, required this.placeholder});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: borderRadius10,
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: 350,
          maxHeight: 66.66,
          minWidth: 315,
          minHeight: 60,
        ),
        child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: blur300, sigmaY: blur300),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: backgroundColor.withOpacity(0.2),
              borderRadius: borderRadius10,
            ),
            child: TextField(
              cursorColor: textPrimary,
              cursorOpacityAnimates: true,
              enableSuggestions: true,
              style: AppTextStyles.body(),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.transparent,
                  hintText: placeholder,
                  hintStyle: AppTextStyles.body(),
                  border:
                      const OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the the widget and all other thing are perfect just help me out with the color

Here is the image of both of the outputs
[Initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5MSD.jpg)
[On Focusing the textfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh1ni.jpg)

Note: tried changing surfaceTintColor and elevation didn't help

Comment: both the images looks same to me. Please update the images

Comment: both images are same,

Comment: updated the images